# How to set Templated Content from a Static Resource

Tags: wpf, triggers, setter, controltemplate

### Problem

In a `ControlTemplate` for a `ToggleButton` I have a trigger for `IsChecked="True"` and another for `False`.

```
<Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True" >
    <Setter TargetName="contentPresenter" Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ContentChecked}">
                <Binding Path="(ToggleButton.Content)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                <Binding Path="(ToggleButton.IsChecked)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"></Binding>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Trigger>

<Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="False">
    <Setter TargetName="contentPresenter" Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ContentChecked}">
                <Binding Path="(ToggleButton.Content)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                <Binding Path="(ToggleButton.IsChecked)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"></Binding>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

This works perfectly but its not too DRY.

### Attempted Solution

I was hoping to the boilerplate to `ControlTemplate.Resources` and add it to the trigger using a *StaticResource* binding. Like this...

```
<ControlTemplate.Resources>

    <SetterBaseCollection x:Key="ContentSetter">
        <Setter TargetName="contentPresenter" Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ContentChecked}">
                    <Binding Path="(ToggleButton.Content)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                    <Binding Path="(ToggleButton.IsChecked)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"></Binding>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </SetterBaseCollection>

</ControlTemplate.Resources>
```

... and reference it something like...

```
<Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True"
         Setters="{StaticResource ContentSetter}" >
</Trigger>
```

But this fails because there is no "Setter" for `Setters`.

How can I get rid of this boilerplate code?

### Background

I'm using `MultiBinding` with `IMultiValueConverter` to pass the current value of `IsChecked` to a *Converter* to decide what value to return. The property that I am passing to the *Setter* is *Content* and I'm passing a `List<string>` to the converter which takes responsibility for which `List` Item to return based on the passed value of `IsChecked`.

### Edit - Solution

Based on the suggestion from @Ash, I moved the MultiBinding onto the `ContentPresenter.Content` element of the Template and deleted the triggers all together.

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                        ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" Focusable="False"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">

    <ContentPresenter.Content>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ContentChecked}">
            <Binding Path="(ToggleButton.Content)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
            <Binding Path="(ToggleButton.IsChecked)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"></Binding>
        </MultiBinding>
    </ContentPresenter.Content>

</ContentPresenter>
```

Comment: setters are identical in both triggers. so what is the point to use triggers in the frist place? use that setter inside style setters.

Comment: @ASh actually it's a Template, not a s Style, but I see what you mean: just add a converter on the binding to Content in the Template's ContentPresenter... I'll try that.

Comment: Worked like a charm @ASh; post an answer if you like and I will accept.

Comment: i don't really want to post an answer since you wrote working code yourself :)

Comment: @Ash, the question title is a bit out of sync with the question in the text: which you answered. I just changed the code based on your insight.  Given the title and the fact that the solution only works because all the possible states were included in the triggers, can you possibly answer the question about how to reference triggers in a `ResourceDictionary`?

Comment: i can't answer "how to reference triggers in a ResourceDictionary" because i don't know. i doubt it is possible to do it so strightforward as in Attempted Solution.

Comment: Ok @ASh, just thought I'd ask ;) thanks for the help!